# JMeter falla con Chromedriver headless

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, chromedriver

Tengo unas pruebas con WebDriverSampler en Jmeter que me funcionan correctamente con chromedriver. Es un script en selenium que abre una página web y comprueba que contiene una serie de elementos. Todo funciona correcto hasta que he probado con la opción headless de chromedriver.

En este caso me salta la excepción "Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath:..." como si no existiera dicho elemento a aún no se cargara. No sé que puede pasar, pues si dejo de utilizar la opción headless, si que funciona todo correcto y encuentra el elemento que realmente existe.

Este es un ejemplo del código utilizado (funciona sin la opción headless):

```
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 30);
var conditions = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();

WDS.browser.get('http://mi-app/');

try{
  wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath('/ruta_de elemento_existente')));
  WDS.log.info('OK')
}catch(e){
    WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    WDS.sampleResult.setResponseMessage('Fail');
    WDS.log.error(e.message)
}

try{
  wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath('/ruta_de elemento2_existente')));
  WDS.log.info('OK2')
}catch(e){
    WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    WDS.sampleResult.setResponseMessage('Fail2');
    WDS.log.error(e.message)
}

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar con este problema, pues necesito utilizar la opción headless.
Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: ¿Puede mostrar un ejemplo de un script y una aplicación web que está probando?

Comment: Editado en el post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código parece correcto. Si está seguro de la corrección de xpath Por lo tanto:
  1. [Comprueba la versión](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) de Google Chrome y chromedriver que usas.
  2. ¿Qué pasa si usas PhantomJS driver or [Firefox Headless](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2017/10/selenium-redline13-integration/)?

> If you are using Chrome version 73, please download ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20
>   If you are using Chrome version 72, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69
>   If you are using Chrome version 71, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 71.0.3578.137

Para evitar esto, configure un tamaño de navegador "seguro" y fijo cuando comience la prueba:

```
WDS.browser.manage().window().setPosition(new pkg.Point(0, 0))
WDS.browser.manage().window().setSize(new pkg.Dimension(1280, 1024))
```

Comment: Utilizo:
- Google Chrome 72.0.3626.119
- Chromedriver 2.46

Con PhantomJS me salta la misma excepcion. No pasa con todos los elementos solo con algunos, que suelen estar en la pare inferior de la página. Se puede deber a algo de resolución o algo por el estilo? Gracias.

Comment: Lo dicho, es algo que tiene que ver con la resolución o el tamaño de ventana. He hecho una captura del momento del error y la app se está ejecutando en modo móvil(lo cual cambia casi toda) por eso no encuentra el elemento porque no está. Hay alguna forma de hacer que se ejecute en headless y con el tamaño de resolución de un monitor normal?

Comment: Para evitar esto, configure un tamaño de navegador "seguro" y fijo cuando comience la prueba